# the application Settings has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-hero

I've installed few new apps; and when I went to deinstall some of them; I got this error.
Now I'm wondering is there a way to "fix this error"? I can still deinstall apps using adb from command line

my configuration : htc hero , 2.1, unrooted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that old installation of Locale was making problems; since after uninstalling it problems disappeared.

I still don't understand how is it possible for app to influence android systems so badly, since every app should run in it's own sandbox, but at least problem is solved.